# Add body #id based on url

Tags: javascript

Need help! I've been looking for a solution for this seemingly simple task but can't find an exact one. Anyway, I'm trying to add custom #id to the  tag based on the page's URL. The script I'm using works ok when the URLs are like these below.

```
- http://localhost.com/index.html
- http://localhost.com/page1.html
- http://localhost.com/page2.html
-> on this level, <body> gets ids like #index, #page1, #page2, etc...
```

My question is, how can I make the body #id still as #page1 or #page2 even when viewing subpages like this?

```
- http://localhost.com/page1/subpage1
- http://localhost.com/page2/subpage2
```

Here's the JS code I'm using (found online)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
    var getLast = pathname.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1];
    var truePath = getLast.replace(".html",""); 
            if(truePath === "") { 
                    $("body").attr("id","index");
            }
            else { 
                    $("body").attr("id",truePath);
            }       
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: Thanks for all the replies! Basically I just want to put custom background images on every pages based on their body#id. >> js noob here.

```
http://localhost.com/page2/subpage2 - > my only problem is how to make the id as #page2 and not #subpage2 on this link.
```

Comment: Have you considered setting the body id value in the jsp or html source instead of setting it with javascript?

Comment: you already have code. does it work? if not -- what is the issue?

Comment: That code would work the same for either url

Comment: @Neal it works but when viewing this page http://localhost.com/page1/subpage1, the body#id becomes #subpage1 instead of #page1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the javascript `split` function might be of help here.  For example (untested, but the general idea):

```
var url = window.location.href.replace(/http[s]?:\/\//, '').replace('.html', '');
var segments = url.split('/');

$('body').id = segments[0];
```

Also, you might want to consider using classes instead of ID's.  This way you could assign every segment as a class...

```
var url = window.location.href.replace(/http[s]?:\/\//, '').replace('.html', '');
var segments = url.split('/');

for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    $('body').addClass(segments[i]);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Glad it worked.  Couple of notes if you're planning on using this for-real:  If you ever have an extension besides .html that will get picked up in the class name.  You can account for this by changing that replace to a regex...

```
var url = window.location.href.replace(/http[s]?:\/\//, '');
// Trim extension
url = url.replace(/\.(htm[l]?|asp[x]?|php|jsp)$/,'');
```

If there will ever be querystrings on the URL you'll want to filter those out too *(this is the one regex I'm not 100% on)*...

```
url = url.replace(/\?.+$/,'');
```

Also, it's a bit inefficient to have the `$('body')` in every for loop "around" as this causes jQuery to have to re-find the body tag.  A more performant way to do this, especially if the sub folders end up 2 or 3 deep would be to find it once, then "cache" it to a variable like so..

```
var $body = $('body');
for ( ... ) {
   $body.addClass( ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your 2nd code using classes and it successfully added .page2 (and .subpage2) to the <body>. :)

Comment: Added some improvements if you're using the code as-was (the past tense version of as-is).

Comment: Hi thanks again! Yes, I'm using your code as-is. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is only going to select the last part of the url.

var getLast = pathname.match(/.*/(.*)$/)[1];

You're matching anything (.*), followed by a slash, followed by anything (this time, capturing this value) and then pulling out the first match, which is the only match.

If you really want to do this (and I have my doubts, this seems like a bad idea) then you could just use window.location.pathname, since that already has the fullpath in there.

edit: You really *shouldn't* need to do this because the URL for the page is already a unique identifier. I can't really think of any situation where you'd need to have a unique id attribute for the body element on a page. Anytime where you're dealing with that content (either from client side javascript, or from a scraper) you should already have a unique identifier - the URL.

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I basically would want to put custom background images on every page based on body#id.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  Basically, it sets the `id` to whatever folder or filename appears after the domain, but won't include a file extension.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").attr("id",window.location.pathname.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the first part of the path instead of the last:

```
var getFirst = pathname.match(/^\/([^\/]*)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pages all have a common name as in your example ("page"), you could modify your script including changing your match pattern to include that part:

```
var getLast = pathname.match(/\/(page\d+)\//)[1];
```

The above would match "page" followed by a number of digits (omitting the 'html' ending too).